# Value from instance of class set to 0

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get the basis for creating an array of controls in Windows Forms, and I've implemented code I saw on MSDN so that it can work for textboxes, but I've yet to find a solution. It seems that the values numRows and numCols are set to 0 although I set them in Form1.cs. I'm new to this way of getters and setters so I may be setting them up incorrectly.

Form1.cs:

```
namespace SOS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int          numTextBoxes = 100;
              TextBoxArray board;
        public Form1()
        {
            board = new TextBoxArray(this);
            board.Cols = 10;
            board.Rows = 10;
            for(int i = 0; i < numTextBoxes; i++)
            {
                board.AddNewTextBox();
            }
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

TextBoxArray.cs:

```
namespace SOS
{
    class TextBoxArray : System.Collections.CollectionBase
    {
        private const    int                       vertOffset = 25;
        private const    int                       horzOffset = 100;
        private          int                       numRows;
        private          int                       numCols;
        private readonly System.Windows.Forms.Form hostForm;

        public TextBoxArray(System.Windows.Forms.Form host)
        {
            hostForm = host;
            this.AddNewTextBox();
            numRows = 1;
            numCols = -1;
        }

        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return (System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)this.List[index];
            }
        }

        public int Rows
        {
            get
            {
                return numRows;
            }
            set
            {
                numRows = value;
            }
        }

        public int Cols
        {
            get
            {
                return numCols;
            }
            set
            {
                numCols = value;
            }
        }

        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.List.Add(txtBox);
            hostForm.Controls.Add(txtBox);
            txtBox.Top = (numRows != -1) ? (((Count - 1) % numRows) + 1) * vertOffset : vertOffset * Count;
            txtBox.Left = (numCols != -1) ? (((Count - 1) % numCols) + 1) * horzOffset : horzOffset * Count;
            txtBox.Tag = this.Count;
            txtBox.Text = "";
            return txtBox;
        }

        public void Remove()
        {
            if (this.Count > 0)
            {
                hostForm.Controls.Remove(this[this.Count - 1]);
                this.List.RemoveAt(this.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing an `this.AddNewTextBox();` in the constructor of `TextBoxArray`. At the moment in time when that occurs, you haven't yet set up the values of  `numRows` and `numCols` by way of **parameter injection**, i.e. you only set `board.Cols = 10;` after the constructor call.

You should consider **constructor injection**, i.e. adding the number of rows and columns as parameters to the `TextBoxArray` class' constructor, and initializing the `numRows` and `numCols` with those values passed in before the call to `this.AddNewTextBox();`

Although, I don't really understand why you feel the need to call `this.AddNewTextBox();` in the constructor. You end up with one textbox already inside the board by default.

Comment: Oh I see, the text boxes are showing now and I'll add another constructor that has those parameters, but the text boxes are showing in a diagonal formation, any suggestions?